# Different color (Per group) addPolylines in Leaflet R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDcDz.png)

I am visualizing the patient's movement. So I want to change the path color for each patient ID. How can I do this?

```
leaflet(patientroute_data)%>%
setView(lng=126.9784, lat=37.566, zoom=6) %>%
addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
addCircles(lng=~longitude, lat=~latitude, color='#006633')%>%
addPolylines(lng=~longitude, lat=~latitude,group=~patient_id,  weight=.5)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide some [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to maximize you chances of obtaining help. If you cannot share you data you can find some dummy data to illustrate your issue.

Comment: you have a parameter color in the `addPolylines`, the idea is to assign a color to each id. You can have a close example for `addPolygons` [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html).